# Is it better to drop a MySQL database before doing a restore?

Tags: mysql

I have been doing a ton of database restores lately and have been thinking about better ways to do things. One thing I am not sure of is what is the best order of operations in terms of backup and restore using mysqldump.

Right now I always drop the existing database and then do the restore but I wonder if its better to simply do the restore over the database without bothering to drop it first. Does it matter? Is there a reason to do it one way or the other?

Comment: You can even add the `--add-drop-database` argument to mysqldump, so that it is automatically done for you when you restore.

Comment: Thanks! I really need to script this out and that would be a good way to save some clicks

Comment: Can anyone answer how much slower it might be, I'm sitting here wondering whether I should stop my restore, drop the database and restart the restore? (my restores takeabout 10 minutes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If DB's structure wasn't modified between dump/restore `drop table` or even `truncate table` is enough. If some modification has been made then you can get some residues from the previous versions without `drop database`.

Anyway `drop database` is significantly faster as far as mysql do not have to keep DB's "ACID"ity.